# How to compare two tables A & B which are different structure

Tags: sql-server, msbi

How to compare two tables A & B which are different structure, I need to check whether data in table A(2 columns) exists in Table B(any of 8 columns) what is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the tables contain. Are the tables linked? What should the result be? Only yes/no or records or columns from A or B or both? Please explain!

Comment: The Table A has two column and table B got 8 column, I need to compare values in  column of tabe A exists in any of the 8 columns in table B. The tables is not linked. i t is just like a validation. Thanks

Comment: So if the values of either in the two A columns are in either of the 8 B columns, you have a match?

Answer (score 2):

If the following queries return a row, then values of one of the two columns of A exist in at least one of the eight columns of B

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.Id
FROM B
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE
        B.c1 = A.c1 OR B.c2 = A.c1 OR B.c3 = A.c1 OR B.c4 = A.c1 OR
        B.c5 = A.c1 OR B.c6 = A.c1 OR B.c7 = A.c1 OR B.c8 = A.c1 OR
        B.c1 = A.c2 OR B.c2 = A.c2 OR B.c3 = A.c2 OR B.c4 = A.c2 OR
        B.c5 = A.c2 OR B.c6 = A.c2 OR B.c7 = A.c2 OR B.c8 = A.c2)
```

In Transact-SQL you can also specify expressions in the IN list, not just constants. This allows this slightly shorter variant

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.Id
FROM B
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE
        A.c1 IN (B.c1, B.c2, B.c3, B.c4, B.c5, B.c6, B.c7, B.c8) OR
        A.c2 IN (B.c1, B.c2, B.c3, B.c4, B.c5, B.c6, B.c7, B.c8)
    )
```

See also: [IN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Or you can invert the two tables

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.Id
FROM A
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE
        A.c1 IN (B.c1, B.c2, B.c3, B.c4, B.c5, B.c6, B.c7, B.c8) OR
        A.c2 IN (B.c1, B.c2, B.c3, B.c4, B.c5, B.c6, B.c7, B.c8)
    )
```

Yet another variant is

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.Id
FROM A CROSS JOIN B
WHERE
    A.c1 IN (B.c1, B.c2, B.c3, B.c4, B.c5, B.c6, B.c7, B.c8) OR
    A.c2 IN (B.c1, B.c2, B.c3, B.c4, B.c5, B.c6, B.c7, B.c8)
```

If the query is slow, it's worth testing the different variants to see whether one is more performing. The `TOP 1` clause is important for performance, as the query execution will stop as soon as a match is found.